# AngularJS & Modules - Can access controller properties, but can't fire events

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, browserify, angularjs-controller

I'm using browserify to include my controllers etc. as modules:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [...])
var LoginCtrl = require('./controllers/Login');
```

Where I define said controller as follows:

```
var LoginCtrl = function() { ... };
module.exports = LoginCtrl;
```

This works perfectly fine, the issue comes when I need to include a controller on a 'per element' basis using `ng-controller` The only way I can do so without error is to explicitly define the controller on the `app` module after its declaration:

```
var app = angular.module('app', [...])
var NavigationCtrl = require('./controllers/Navigation');
app.controller('NavCtrl', NavigationCtrl);
```

However, though this silences the errors within the console, I can not get the controller to respond to events:

#### view

```
<div class="header" ng-controller="NavCtrl as nav>
  <button ng-click="nav.login()">Login</button>
  <span>{{ nav.prop }}</span>
...
```

or

```
<div class="header" ng-controller="NavCtrl>
  <button ng-click="login()">Login</button>
  <span>{{ prop }}</span>
...
```

#### controller

```
var NavCtrl = function($scope) {
    // these show up
    this.prop = "Hi"
    $scope.prop = "Hi"

    // these do nothing
    $scope.login = function() {
       console.log("no-show");
    };
    this.login = function() {
       console.log("no-show");
    };
};

module.exports = NavCtrl;
```

As I understand it, declaring controllers as variables and exporting them is no longer the correct way of doing angular development. Though, I'm not sure if that applies given the use of Browserify & Gulp (aka how my project is structured).

I'd really appreciate if someone could shed some light on how / why this is happening? Thanks again.

Comment: In case you made a typo in your question, do check your names. `app.controller('NavCtrl', NavigationCtrl)` above should use `NavCtrl` as the second argument, unless you actually defined your controller as `var NavigationCtrl = ...`. This is likely why you cannot access things defined inside your controller.

Comment: @miqid as mentioned, if I change it to `NavCtrl` as you specified, I get the following error in the console: `Uncaught ReferenceError: NavCtrl is not defined`. As it is in the post, I can access the properties defined at compile time, just not the events at run time (where in, I assume, my issue lies).